# Onclick FIle Upload DOM PHP Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, onclick

I am trying to upload a file to a PHP script I've made when a button is clicked.  I am only in my first few hours of JavaScript, and I really don't understand the structuring of JS v Dynamically Loading HTML, so here I am.

When the menu link is clicked, it loads the HTML from another file fine.  The HTML that is loads has a file upload form with a disabled submit button.  When that button is hit, I am trying to do a XMLHttpRequest to the server and upload that file.  My first attempt, it couldn't find the DOM element with that ID because it wasn't loaded yet.  So, I moved that function inside the function that loads the HTML when the menu is clicked.  Now, I do not receive the null error, but nothing happens when I click the button?  Why is the submit button onclick event not firing?

HTML that is loaded

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
<p>
    Please upload a Material List.
</p>
</br>
</br>
<form id="form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <p>                 
        <label class="label" for="file">Material List</label>               
        <input class="file-input" type="file" name="file" id="file"/>                   
    </p>
</br>
</br>
    <p>
        <input id="submit" value="Upload File" disabled="disabled" type="submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript that loads that HTML and is supposed to be setting the onclick listener...

```
$(document).on("click","#mrp-new",function(e){
    $("#container").load("../html/mrp_new_order.html");
    $(document).on("click","#submit",function(e)
    {
        var file = this.files[0];       
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", file);        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '../php/mrp_upload.php', true);        

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e)
        {
            if (e.lengthComputable)
            {
                var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
            }
        };

        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            if (this.status == 200)
            {
                var resp = JSON.parse(this.response);
                alert('Server got:', resp);
                /*var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.src = resp.dataUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(image);*/
            };
        };      
        xhr.send(fd);
    }, false);
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set an onclick, or any listener for that matter to a disabled button.  I found out after Google'ing for a bit.

I changed

`<input id="submit" value="Upload File" disabled="disabled" type="submit"/>`

to

`<button id="submit" type="button"/>`

and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Read about document ready- $.ready [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and Ajax call with jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

load function as a second parameter can use function which will be called after load is done. [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#container").load("../html/mrp_new_order.html", function() {
   alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Try to listen to submit event of form instead

```
$("#container").load("../html/mrp_new_order.html", function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
      alert('Submit button was pressed');
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If the document wasn't ready when that function was called, I would received a type error saying I can't assign a function to null, correct? @Damian0o

Comment: Your first bit spits an alert as expected, but I get nothing when I add your second piece of code and press the submit button.  Would disabling the button in the HTML be the cause?